# The command redirect_to "http://google.com" doesn't appear to be working!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

So I have the final line in my controller:

```
    redirect_to "http://google.com"
```

And the prod log has:

```
Redirected to http://google.com
Completed in 8ms (DB: 4) | 302 Found [http://www.exmaple.com/728zz5d/delete_stuff]
```

And the web page still had the original info - I'm not sent to google??? What am I not understanding?

Comment: are you rendering before your redirect? redirect_to "http://google.com" works fine for me rails 2.3.8

Comment: "And the web page still had the original info." I think he is rendering before redirect.

Comment: Can we see the full controller action, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have revisited this code and not sure what I did to fix as I reworked parts of it. I gather that I was using the wrong rails call, a **link_to_function** instead of a **link_to** as well, I am now using the _url helper so the final line is (to a local page)

> redirect_to home_url